# Cluster manager for Linux/Java processes, log gathering

Tags: logging, cluster-computing, failover

I have some Java servers (though Java in fact doesn't matter here, it can be any executable) which I want to run on multiple machines. Is there some cluster management software, which would allow me to say, for example "start 3 instances of service A, and 5 instaces of service B". In case one node dies, start the services on another server.

It would also be nice to have some kind of an admin console, where I could see which servers work, which services work were etc. (Of course with a nice dashboard with lots of green ;) ). Or at least a REST interface to get that info easily.

Going a step further, such a cluster manager could take care of gathering logs from the services, and alerting an adinistrators if there are errors in any of them. Or maybe that's a separate service?

Does such a thing exist? (preferrably in an open-source version of course)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) might be useful in your case ?